# TikZ, PGFPlots, or GNUplot: plotting a curve without the known function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I would like to make a plot of a function that has an overshoot of 25% and then settles with subtle oscillations at 100%.  I would like to create it in one of the listed packages or in gnus case add on to PGFPlots.  Unfortunately, I don't know the function I just have an image so I don't know how to start creating it.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that ultimately a problem of mathematics not TeX? Even if you can't find the function, you could presumably do a scan, work out the point positions and plot them.

Comment: @JosephWright I am not necessarily looking for an exact plot just something that has this behavior since we can always re label the axes.  I think it may be possible to mimic this with TeX alone.  I just don't know where or how to start without the equation.

Comment: My point is you have to have _something_ to plot, but that has nothing to with TeX.

Comment: This looks like the response of a controller, e.g. a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).

Comment: I'd be tempted to plot one curve for `t\in[0,0.01]` and then another curve for `t\geq 0.01`; the second curve looks like it could be (something like) `sin(t)*exp(-t)+1`. You'd have to mess with the period (and possibly a horizontal shift) to get it oscillating the way you want.

Comment: It is an under-damped oscillator which is commonly explained in RLC circuit or its mechanical dual.

Comment: @JosephWright I have estimated the solution to be `1-\frac{e^{-\zeta  t \omega } \sin \left(\sec (\zeta )+\sqrt{1-\zeta ^2} t \omega \right)}{\sqrt{1-\zeta ^2}}` were `zeta = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\pi }{\log (4)}\right)^2}}` and `\omega = \frac{100 \pi }{\sqrt{1-\zeta ^2}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been able produce the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenx
% Euler for math | Palatino for rm | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}% rm
\linespread{1.05}% Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}% ss //  http://ctan.org/pkg/helvet
\usepackage{courier}% tt // http://ctan.org/pkg/courier
\usepackage{eulervm}  %  http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm
% a better implementation of the euler package (not in gwTeX)
\normalfont%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{textcomp}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.9}
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{0.403713}
\pgfmathsetmacro\w{343.386319715305}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymax = 1.3,
    ymin = 0,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = .05,
    ytick = {0, 1.25},
    xtick = {0, 0.01},
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = left,
    xlabel = {$t(sec)$},
    ylabel = {$y(t)$}
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 100, smooth]
    gnuplot[id = exp, domain = 0:.05]
    {1 - exp(-\z*\w*x)/sqrt(1 - \z^2)*sin(\w*x*sqrt(1 - \z^2) + 1/cos(\z))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I change `1*10^{-2}` to display as 0.01?

Comment: For your question, use `scaled x ticks=false` and `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` in the axis options.

Answer (score 2):

Just for a starting point. It is not a complete answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /xi .125 def
    /tau .25 def
    /rho {xi 2 exp neg 1 add sqrt} def
    /amp 3 def
}
\def\f(#1){amp*(1-3^(-xi*(#1)/tau)*(cos((#1)*rho/tau)+sin((#1)*rho/tau)*xi/rho))}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=300](-1,-1)(11,7)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(10.5,6.5)[$t$,0][$v(t)$,90]
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{0}{10}{\f(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]