# Step response in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm fairly new to Tikz and up until now just made some block diagrams. But now I'd like to recreate the following picture showing the characteristics of the step response.

[image]

I don't even know where to start let alone how to finish it.

Edit:
The function has the following form:

```
y(t) = 1-exp(-0.5*t)*(cos(sqrt(1-0.5^2)*t)+0.5/(sqrt(1-0.5^2))*sin(sqrt(1-0.5^2)*t))
```

**Edit:**
Alright, this is now my final result. Thanks everyone for helping.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=9cm,
            height=6cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=0, xmax=15,
            ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
            xlabel=$t$,
            ylabel={$y(t)$},
            xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
            ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
            xtick={0, 0.4726, 1.79398, 1.96605, 3.2236, 11.0855},
            xticklabels={$0$, $$, $$, $$, $t_p$, $t_s$},
            every x tick/.style={black},
            ytick={0, 0.1, 0.9, 1, 1.3714},
            yticklabels={$0$, $0.1$, $0.9$, $1$, $M_p$},
            every y tick/.style={black}
        ]
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(0.4726,0.1)} -- (axis cs:0,0.1);
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(0.4726,0.1)} -- (axis cs:0.4726,0);
        %
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(1.79398,0.9)} -- (axis cs:0,0.9);
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(1.79398,0.9)} -- (axis cs:1.79398,0);
        %
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(1.96605,1)} -- (axis cs:1.96605,0);
        %
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(3.2236,1.3714)} -- (axis cs:0,1.3714);
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(3.2236,1.3714)} -- (axis cs:3.2236,0);
        %
        \addplot[black, densely dotted] coordinates{(11.0855,1.025)} -- (axis cs:11.0855,0);

        \addplot[black, dashed] coordinates{(15,1)} -- (axis cs:0,1);
        %
        \addplot[cyan, dashed] coordinates{(15,0.975)} -- (axis cs:0,0.975);
        \addplot[cyan, dashed] coordinates{(15,1.025)} -- (axis cs:0,1.025);
        %
        \addplot[smooth, 
                 black,
                 thick,
                 mark=none,
                 domain=0:12.4,
                 samples=100]
        {1-exp(-0.3*x)*(cos(deg(sqrt(1-0.3^2)*x))+0.3/(sqrt(1-0.3^2))*sin(deg(sqrt(1-0.3^2)*x)))};
        %
        \addplot[black, thick] coordinates{(15,0.9872)} -- (axis cs:12.4,0.9872);
        %
        \coordinate (trleft) at (axis cs:0,0);
        \coordinate (trright) at (axis cs:1.96605,0);
        %
        \coordinate (tr1left) at (axis cs:0.4726,0);
        \coordinate (tr1right) at (axis cs:1.79398,0);
        %
        \coordinate (ess1) at (axis cs:14,1.1);
        \coordinate (ess2) at (axis cs:14,1);
        \coordinate (ess3) at (axis cs:14,0.9872);
        \coordinate (ess4) at (axis cs:14,0.8872);
    \end{axis}

    \draw [densely dotted] (tr1left) -- ++(0,-0.5cm) coordinate (a1);
    \draw [densely dotted](tr1right) -- ++(0,-0.5cm) coordinate (a2);
    \draw [<->] ([yshift=2pt]a1) -- ([yshift=2pt]a2) node [midway,fill=white] {${\scriptstyle \hat{t}_r}$};

    \draw [densely dotted] (trleft) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (b1);
    \draw [densely dotted](trright) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (b2);
    \draw [<->] ([yshift=2pt]b1) -- ([yshift=2pt]b2) node [midway,fill=white] {$t_r$};

    \draw [->] (ess1) node [right] {$\bar{\epsilon}$} -- (ess2);
    \draw [<-] (ess3) -- (ess4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following.

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have the equation of the plot ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This seems to be a question "do-it-for-me" ... please show what you try so far.

Comment: You could have a look at these [Pgfplots examples](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html). None of these are of course PID-controllers, but might get you started. I also found the [TikZ, PGFPlots, or GNUplot: plotting a curve without the known function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168425/tikz-pgfplots-or-gnuplot-plotting-a-curve-without-the-known-function), which I think is basically what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TikZ, PGFPlots, or GNUplot: plotting a curve without the known function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168425/tikz-pgfplots-or-gnuplot-plotting-a-curve-without-the-known-function)

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, I edited the post with what I have so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Thanks @Seamus, you just posted when I removed the MWE and put it in as an answer ;)

Comment: @Pascal I think it is better to put what you have in your question and ask a specific question about what you can't do. Your "answer" is not an answer to any question you really ask in the question.

Comment: @Seamus Well, since I basically asked how one could create such as plot, I do think my "answer" indeed is an answer (or at least part of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the rise time, you could do something along

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=0, xmax=15,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
        xlabel=$t$,
        ylabel={$y(t)$},
        xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
        ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
        xtick={0, 0.4726, 1.79398, 1.96605, 3.2236, 11.0855},
        xticklabels={$0$, $t_{r_1}$, $t_{r_1}$, $t_r$, $t_p$, $t_s$},
        ytick={0, 0.1, 0.9, 1, 1.3714},
        yticklabels={$0$, $0.1$, $0.9$, $1$, $M_p$}
    ]
    \addplot[smooth, 
             black,
             thick,
             mark=none,
             domain=0:12.4,
             samples=100]
    {1-exp(-0.3*x)*(cos(deg(sqrt(1-0.3^2)*x))+0.3/(sqrt(1-0.3^2))*sin(deg(sqrt(1-0.3^2)*x)))};
    %
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(0.4726,0.1)} -- (axis cs:0,0.1);
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(0.4726,0.1)} -- (axis cs:0.4726,0);
    %
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(1.79398,0.9)} -- (axis cs:0,0.9);
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(1.79398,0.9)} -- (axis cs:1.79398,0);
    %
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(1.96605,1)} -- (axis cs:1.96605,0);
    %
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(3.2236,1.3714)} -- (axis cs:0,1.3714);
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(3.2236,1.3714)} -- (axis cs:3.2236,0);
    %
    \addplot[black, dotted] coordinates{(11.0855,1.025)} -- (axis cs:11.0855,0);
    %
    \addplot[black, thick] coordinates{(15,0.9872)} -- (axis cs:12.4,0.9872);
    %
    \addplot[black, dashed] coordinates{(15,1)} -- (axis cs:0,1);
    %
    \addplot[blue, dashed] coordinates{(15,0.975)} -- (axis cs:0,0.975);
    \addplot[blue, dashed] coordinates{(15,1.025)} -- (axis cs:0,1.025);

    \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (axis cs:1.79398,0);

    \end{axis}

    \draw [shorten <=1mm,shorten >=1mm] (a) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (aa);
    \draw (b) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (bb);
    \draw [|<->|] (aa) -- (bb) node [midway,fill=white] {$t_r$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image: Axes with range marker.]

It is important to add the range markers after closing the axes, otherwise they are clipped.

The `e_ss` marker could be constructed from two backwards arrows, `\draw [<-] ...`

Comment: I would use a `spy` thing for the static error....